# Knockout Mapping to image (links) in Json

Tags: jquery, json, html, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Still trying to get the Knockout mapping plugin fine tuned. I'm close, but cannot get the image links from the Json (google books api) to display the images. Not sure if I should be trying to go this deep into the Json on the HTML or restructure the mapped data. I'd be happy either way. Thanks in advance for your help.

HTML...

```
<body>
    <h2>Find Cat in the Hat</h2>
       <div>
            <input id="booksearch" /><input id="btnTest" type="button" value="button" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <table id="bookresults">
                <thead>

                   <tr>
                        <th colspan="6">Books</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: model.items">
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="button" title="Select" value="Select" /></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: volumeInfo.title"></td>
                        <td data-bind="text: volumeInfo.description"></td>
                        <td><table><tbody><!-- ko foreach: volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers --><tr><td data-bind="text: identifier"></td></tr><!-- /ko --></tbody></table></td>
                        <td><table><tbody><!-- ko foreach: volumeInfo.categories --><tr><td data-bind="text: $data"></td></tr><!-- /ko --></tbody></table></td>
                        <td><table><tbody><!-- ko foreach: items.volumeInfo --><tr><td><img data-bind="attr: {src: imageLinks.thumbnail}" /></td></tr><!-- /ko --></tbody></table></td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/ireadabook.js"></script>

</body>
```

js file....

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Knockout Test

    $('#btnTest').click(function () {

        var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=the+Cat+In+The+Hat";
        var viewModel = {};
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

            viewModel.model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

        });

        //Show the results after selected
        $('#bookresults').css("display", "block");

    });

});
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what the problem is...  Or at least what isn't working?  Are you trying to display an image based off of a link you are getting?  Or are you trying to display an image from a src?  Please explain your problem in more detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping plugin creates your viewmodel with the same structure as your source. So you need to access the data in your mapped viewmodel as you would access it from the source.

In your source JSON the `imageLinks` property looks like this:

[image]

As you can see `imageLinks` is not an array but an object (`{}` instead of `[]`), so you don't need the `ko foreach` you can just write:

```
<table>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <img data-bind="attr: {src: volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}" />
             </td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/htf3p/).

Comment: Thanks again nemsev. You are a Knockout Mapping ninja.